# Apache Derby SQL - select number of related rows between two tables

Tags: sql, derby

im using  Apache Derby open source Database,
i have two tables :

QUESTIONS: 
Q_id - *auto increment integer* 

Qtext - *varchar(300)*

ANSWERS: 
A_id - *auto increment integer* 

Atext - *varchar(300)* 

Q_id  - *FOREIGN KEY integer not null* 
 
for each question there's more than one answer, and it can be that a question has no answers so what i want to do is to write a ([Apache derby sql](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/crefsqlj39374.html)) statement which does the follows :

For each question in QUESTIONS table i want to **count** how many answers it has in ANSWERS TABLE, **most important** is for question that has no answers i want the result result to be 0.

Example : 
[SEE EXAMPLE IN THIS PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeuSB.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Questions.QText
, count(Answers.AText)
from Questions
left outer join Answers on Answers.Q_Id = Questions.Q_Id
group by Questions.QText
```

Update:

You can use MAX on the question text that way you won't have to group by q_text

```
select Questions.Q_id
, max(Questions.qtext)
, COUNT(Answers.q_id)
from Questions
left join Answers on Answers.Q_id = Questions.Q_id
group by Questions.Q_id
```

Comment: i dont wanna group by Questions.QText because it may be duplicated Qtext its not a primary key, your answer works on this example, but i want a general one, so i tried to change select Questions.QText to select Questions.*  -- and to group by Questions.Q_id ---- and it didn't work

Comment: @ssm6366 See the update if I got you right this time.

Comment: yes its true now, but can you tell me what is the max(Questions.Qtext) is for ?, and how it doesn't affect if there's duplicated Qtext?

Comment: @ssm6366 Because you're using aggregate function and group by clauses, if you don't use another aggregate for q_text you'll have to use it in the group by. If you want to group by Q_Id only and not group by Q_text, you can use max (or min) for q_text so you don't have to include it in group by. It doesn't affect with duplicate qtext because you're grouping by q_id, which is unique. So max(qtext) (or min) will return the only q_text for that Q_id.

Comment: Or, group by q_id, qtext. Or, just leave qtext out entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation.